# Accuracy of the polynomial trendline in excel

Tags: excel, regression, curve-fitting, trendline

There is no change in trendline for 4th, 5th and 6th order polynomial trendlines for the given data. I think this is because of the 15-digits precision limit in excel which affects the calculation for polynomial trendline.

I would like to verify the accuracy of polynomial trendline in excel for the following data

**X-values:** 1.00
1.00
2.00
10.00
23.00
23.00
68.00

**Y-values:** 38.32
13.76
70.74
70.74
10
10
523.41

Is there any standard or benchmark available to verify the correctness of trendline?

[image: trendline]

Comment: @all, if my question is not clear or you are not able to understand it, please make a comment so I can modify it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason why there is no change for 4th, 5th and 6th order polynomial trendlines

For drawing a 4th order polynomial curve, excel needs 5 data points.

Similarly, for drawing 5th order curve, excel needs 6 data points but as we can see there is only 5 data points in the chart. So the curve for 5th order polynomial appears similar to the 4th order polynomial

Similarly, for drawing 6th order curve, excel needs 7 data points but as we can see there is only 5 data points. So the curve for 6th order polynomial appears similar to the 4th order polynomial

Comment: The same thing will happen even with all 7 data points. This is because there are only 5 unique points for the independent variable (x-values). Each collection of points with an identical x-value will have a single y-value that minimizes the sim of the square residuals. So in this case, a regression curve will minimize the sum of the square residuals simply by bisecting the two y-values at x = 1.00. The same idea applies with the identical y-values at x = 23.00